# What is a way to append and hide multiple div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So lets say I have a bunch of messages to display to the user but as they dismiss one I want to apend another with data from ajax

```
jQuery('body').on('change', '.hide_msg_announcement', function(e) {
        jQuery(".hide_msg_announcement").hide();
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/announcement/dismiss-ajax',
                dataType:'json',
                async:true,
                type: 'POST', cache:false,
                data:{strID: $(this).data("msg")},
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                },
                success: function(result){

                    announcementContent = '<div class="fade in pi-alert-warning pi-no-margin-bottom 
                                          hide_msg_announcement">'+
                        '<p class="pi-weight-600 pi-no-margin-bottom hide_msg_announcement">'+
                            '<span class="pi-text-dark"> '+ result.formal_announcement_content +' 
                              </span>'+
                        '</p>'+
                    '<div class=" pull-right checkbox checkbox-inline" style="margin-top: -16px;">'+
                    '<input type="checkbox" class="hide_msg_announcement" name="hide_msg" 
                            id="hide_msg_announcement" data-msg="'+ result.formal_announcement_id +'">'+
                    '<label class="pi-smaller-text pi-text-grey" 
                      for="hide_msg_announcement">dismiss</label>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>';
                    $('.div_content_announcement').append(announcementContent).slideDown("slow");
                },
            });
```

then with the server code I am storing the ID of the announcement/message in cookies so I know which was dismissed and I don't show it again.

Right now it properly dismisses an announcement/message and appends the next one just like I want it but then after that it stops only after doing it one time

Comment: you cant use `'` quotes for multi-lines, check error log

Comment: You're better off using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) anyway.

Comment: What are you expecting the raise a change event? It's connected to elements with the *class* "hide_msg_announcement", but it looks like you might want it to be attached to the *id* "hide_msg_announcement".

Comment: its a checkbox, the event is working fine and hiding the announcement, sending to ajax and loading the next announcement properly its just not doing it the second time

Comment: it works now, I just changed apend to prepend